# getting the sum of all instances of Entity B from a given instance of Entity A

Tags: ios, core-data, one-to-many, nsdecimalnumber

I have a to-many relationship between Entity A and Entity B (iOS Core Data app).  I need to get the sum of the NSDecimalNumber attribute of all instances of Entity B from a given instance of Entity A.  Does anyone have a tutorial or example of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use the [@sum collection operator](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE) thusly:

```
NSNumber *theSum=[ObjectA.objectBs valueForKey:@"@sum.numericalAttribute"];
```

Comment: Thanks, @TechZen.  the compiler complains that it's not KeyValueCoding compliant.  Do I need to set up a KeyValueObserver?  If so, does that code go in the model class or in my controller class?  Thanks again.

Comment: ManagedObjects are automatically key-value compliant. You have to be careful to use the right keypath. So, if your attribute is named `total` then the keypath would be `@sum.total`. Likewise, ObjectA.objectBs must be the correct path using the names in you model. An error saying a managedObject "is not Key-Value coding compliant for key 'whatever'" means that you've given it the wrong keypath. It's usually caused by typos.

Comment: Thanks @TechZen.  Seems I had a typo.  Compiler has stopped complaining about being Key-value compliant.  Now, my problem is where I put this piece of code.  Maybe you could help.  I have a custom table cell, where I have a label that needs to display the sum of all objectBs.  Do I create a method that calculates this?  Here is what I was thinking: - (void)calculateTotalCost{
 NSDecimalNumber *theTotalCost = [Envelope.expenses valueForKey:"@sum.cost"];
 Envelope.totalCost = theTotalCost;
}  Is this the right approach or am I way off base?

Comment: If the calculation is purely for display, then it should go in the tableView datasource object which by default is you tableViewController. You could just drop the line into `– tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` where you configure the cell for display.

Comment: If, however, you want to include it in the data model i.e. as an attribute of an entity, then you should add a transitional attribute to the entity. Provide a custom getter for the attribute with the code and it will recalculate the sum each time the attribute is accessed e.g. for entity `Envelope` you add a transitional attribute `totalCost` and each time you use `something=anEnvelopeObj.totalCost` you get back a freshly calculated sum.

Comment: Thanks again @TechZen for your help.  Here is what I have in my configureCell: NSNumber *theSum = [Envelope.expenses valueForKey:@"@sum.cost"];
 UILabel *envelopeExpensesLabel = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:4];
 envelopeExpensesLabel.text = theSum;  The compiler is complaining that it expects a ':' before token '.' for the collection operator code line.

Comment: Do you have an NSManagedObject subclass defined for `Envelope`? If not you can't use dot syntax and must use `valueForKey:` like: `[[EnvelopeObj valueForKey:@"expenses"] valueForKey:@"@sum.cost"];` If that's not the cause, then you have a missing bracket in the code before the line.

Comment: Well that fixed the compiler complaint, @TechZen.  Now when I run the app and try to add a new "Envelope", I get this error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  [<Envelope 0x9264> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key expenses. with userInfo {
    NSTargetObjectUserInfoKey = Envelope;
    NSUnknownUserInfoKey = expenses;

Comment: I found this link from Jeff Lamarche http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/01/chapter-4-and-tale-of.html  I'm thinking that if "expenses" don't exist yet, then the app crashes?