# KVC Collection Operators on primitive values

Tags: ios, objective-c, primitive, key-value-coding

Can collection operators be used on primitive values?

I have an object that has a primitive property `duration`.

```
@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval duration;
```

I have an `NSArray` of those said objects and I would like to use a collection operation on the array to get the *sum* of the durations. The problem is that `@"@sum.duration"` expects an `NSNumber` instead.

Will I have to do this the old fashioned way, or is there a way to use primitives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From ["Scalar and Structure Support"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/DataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002171-BAJEAIEE)
in the "Key-Value Coding Programming Guide":

> Key-value coding provides support for scalar values and data
>   structures by automatically wrapping and unwrapping NSNumber and
>   NSValue instance values.

So

```
NSNumber *sum = [array valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.duration"];
```

just works, even if `duration` is a scalar property. Small self-contained example:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property(nonatomic, assign) NSTimeInterval duration;
@end

@implementation MyClass
@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        MyClass *obj1 = [MyClass new];
        obj1.duration = 123.4;
        MyClass *obj2 = [MyClass new];
        obj2.duration = 456.7;
        NSArray *array = @[obj1, obj2];

        NSNumber *sum = [array valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.duration"];
        NSLog(@"sum = %@", sum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output: 580.1.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder why I received this error: `Exception: [<__NSArrayM 0xe733040> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key sum.duration.`

Comment: @RileyE: I have tested it before posting the answer. Did you write `@sum.duration` or `sum.duration`?

Comment: @RileyE: I have added a working example to my answer.

Comment: @RileyE, are you trying to use `valueForKey` rather than `valueForKeyPath:`?

Comment: @RobNapier Good catch! I was going off [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251255/getting-the-sum-of-all-instances-of-entity-b-from-a-given-instance-of-entity-a) for some odd reason instead of [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE).

Comment: I'm sorry for any earlier inconvenience, Martin! And thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can always add another property:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSNumber *durationNumber;
```

and implement both the getter and setter:

```
- (NSNumber *)durationNumber {
    return [NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.duration];
}

- (void)setDurationNumber:(NSNumber *)durationNumber {
    self.duration = durationNumber.doubleValue;
}
```

Implementing both the setter and getter inhibits automatic synthesis of the backing ivar.

Comment: Yeah. I thought of that, but doing it the old fashioned way seems to be a more optimal way of doing it. A quick for loop iterator that runs once and no need for `NSNumber` allocation. However, thank you for the answer!